# how to intercept all the get requests and redirect based on the requested url

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my c# web application, I need to intercept all the incoming requests(get) to test if the URL **contains** specific file name (not the file type or extension) or string, based on this information I need to check User's authentication and authorization status and resource's permission status and redirect user to login if required. My question is what is the best place to test this? **Global.asax, http handler, http  module** or ?

p.s. This is a busy website and I need to consider the performance as well. The secure resources are present in the same directory containing the public documents but only database has the access information about public/private.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

As you want to inspect all requests and are not limited to a specific file extension, I'd propose to create a HttpModule. This is also backed by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Typical uses for HTTP modules include the following:
>
> - Security   Because you can examine incoming requests, an HTTP module
>     can perform custom authentication or other security checks before the
>     requested page, XML Web service, or handler is called.

It is also a good choice in terms of performance as the module is run early in the request. If the user is not authorized, he or she is redirected early. In order to increase performance, you can also think about implementing some kind of caching so that you do not have to query the database on each request.

For a walkthrough on how to create a module, see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Implementing the check in Global.asax is also an option, but this ties your solution to this application. You can easily share the module with another project. Using a module is also good from a design point of view as you create a specific module for this task and do not mix functionality as you maybe would in the BeginRequest method of the Global.asax sooner or later.